# EF duplicate values in secondary table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm developing a web application using Entity Framework.

I need do a select and pass values for an `Ilist` but it's returns duplicate values.

```
IQueryable<establishmentInfo> filter = (from x in db.establishments
                                        join t in db.establishment_categories on x.id equals t.establishment
                                        join q in db.categories on t.category equals q.id
                                        where (x.name.ToUpper().Contains(search.ToUpper()))
                                        select new establishmentInfo
                                                   {
                                                       id = x.id,
                                                       name = x.name,
                                                       id_category = q.id,
                                                       category = q.name,
                                                    });

IList<establishmentInfo>establishments = filter.ToList();
```

Establishment table

```
id    name        email
---------------------------
1     AAA         a@a.com
2     BBB         b@b.com
```

Establishment_categories

```
id    establishment    category
-------------------------------
1          1               1
2          1               2
3          2               1
```

Categories

```
id            name
---------------------
1             alpha
2             beta
```

The problem is that return 2 establishments, one with category 1 and other with category 2. I need remove one of these.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The reason you have duplicate `Establishment`s is that you have two records in `Establishment_category` with `establishment` equal to `1`. Do you understand how `join` works?

Comment: What version of EF are you using: EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / EF Core 2.1 / EF Core 3.x?

Comment: So you have a many-many relationship defined by your `establishment_categories` table. Your result set will currently return one record for each of those many-many joins. So if you only want one record for the relationship, you need to decide which of those rows to you want to exclude...

Answer (score 0):

As @NetMage said,your linq statement should return two values that are not repeated.

We can see that there are two records with `establishment` set to `1` in your `Establishment_categories` table. You can check your `establishments`. The `id_category` should be `1`, the `category` should be `alpha`, the other should be `id_category`is `2`, and the `category` should be `beta`.

You can see below image:

[image]

If you only want to get the first data of establishments, you can write the code as follows:

```
IQueryable<Establishment>  filter = (from x in _context.Establishments
                     join t in _context.Establishment_Categories on x.Id equals t.EstablishmentId
                     join q in _context.Categories on t.CategoryId equals q.Id
                     where x.Name.ToUpper().Contains(search.ToUpper())
                     select new Establishment
                     {
                      Id = x.Id,
                      Name = x.Name,
                      CategoryId = q.Id,
                      CategoryName = q.Name,
                     }).Take(1);

        List<Establishment> establishments = filter.ToList();
```

Result:
[image]

By the way, assuming that there are duplicates in your returned data, you can add the `.Distinct()` method after your linq to remove duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I understand your comment but in the explanation I can't do a foreach loop because isn't a list.
I tried use the .Distinct() but I'm doing something wrong.
If I try a filter only establishments and categories, and do the Distinct I get only the result that I want. I can add other filter inside the first result?
Like establishment_filter = establishment_filter....

Comment: According to the code you provided, haven't you already returned a collection of two different objects? So what are your specific needs, please forgive me for not understanding what you mean.